# SFML mouse position and collision loading from file

Tags: c++, position, mouse, collision, sfml

Okay so I have two problems. First off I have made a square that is locked to a grid the same size as my tiles. This is what will be used for changing tiles. It works fine except for when I start scrolling. I know why it is. It's because the mouse position is relative to the window, not the map. I was wondering if there was a way I could code the squares to follow my mouse even when I scroll.

Current code:

```
if (Event.type == sf::Event::MouseMoved)
        {

            rect.setFillColor(sf::Color(255, 0, 255));
            rect.setSize(sf::Vector2f(BLOCKSIZE, BLOCKSIZE));
            int x_offset = (Window.getView().getCenter().x - Window.getSize().x /2);
            int y_offset = (Window.getView().getCenter().y - Window.getSize().y /2);

            rect.setPosition(((sf::Mouse::getPosition(Window).x/32 *32) + (x_offset/32 *32)), ((sf::Mouse::getPosition(Window).y/32 * 32) + (y_offset/32 * 32)));
             std::cout << "Mouse position: x:" << ((sf::Mouse::getPosition(Window).x/32 *32) + (x_offset/32 *32)) << " y:" << ((sf::Mouse::getPosition(Window).y/32 * 32) + (y_offset/32 * 32)) << ")\n\n";
        }
```

Next problem is loading collision.

Code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < CollisionVector.size(); i++)
    {
        //Loop through the height of the MapVector
        for(int j = 0; j < CollisionVector[i].size(); j++)
        {
            sf::RectangleShape rect;
            //If the stored number is 1
            if(CollisionVector[i][j] == 1)
            {
                rect.setFillColor(sf::Color(255, 0, 255));
                rect.setSize(sf::Vector2f(BLOCKSIZE, BLOCKSIZE));
                //Set the position of the rectangle
                rect.setPosition(j * BLOCKSIZE, i * BLOCKSIZE);
            }
            //Draw the rectangle
            Window.draw(rect);
        }
    }
```

I get a blank screen if I add that in. I wanted the rectangles to be transparent but I changed it to pink just in case that was the problem (Which it wasn't)

Screen scrolling code:

```
void Camera::Update(float x, float y)
{
    cameraX = x - (ScreenWidth / 2);
    cameraY = y - (ScreenHeight / 2);

    if (cameraX < 0)
        cameraX = 0.0;
    if (cameraY < 0)
        cameraY = 0.0;

    CameraPosition.reset(sf::FloatRect(cameraX, cameraY, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight));
    CameraPosition.setViewport(sf::FloatRect(0,0,1,1));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one: since you are scrolling by changing the `sf::View`, calculate the view offset and add it to your coordinates:

```
[...]
float x_offset = Window.getView().getCenter().x - Window.getSize().x * .5f;
float y_offset = Window.getView().getCenter().y - Window.getSize().y * .5f;

rect.setPosition(sf::Mouse::getPosition(Window).x/32 * 32 + x_offset, 
            sf::Mouse::getPosition(Window).y/32 * 32 + y_offset;
```

For the second one... uhhh I've got nothing right now. I've checked SFML and a `sf::RectangleShape` is default-initialized to have a size of (0, 0) so that's not the issue. Maybe the problem is in surrounding code?

Comment: Edited OP with scrolling code and could you post an example of how to fix 2? Anywhere I put the draw function, I get a white screen.

Comment: The first one works but it doesn't grid lock the rectangle like before.

Comment: Add the offsets outside the parantheses, then.

Comment: Okay I basically got it working except after I've scrolled it moves the purple rectangle when my mouse moves past the middle of the rectangles on the y axis and moves the rectangle when my mouse moves past the middle of the rectangles on the x axis